# How to programmatically check If string is not to wide to fit onto the screen in Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a custom `ListView`. inside a custom ListView, I have a TextView & it's look like this

[image]

Now, my question is

1) is there any way to check If names is not to wide to fit onto the screen in Android ? I mean I don't want two lines. Like here `Wachler` is on 2nd line. So, how do I check if all names are wide to fit onto the screen in one line.

Comment: If text not fit to width then what you want to do?

Comment: `I mean I don't want two lines`, then what you want to do if content is more than 1 line?

Comment: Try using singleLine="true" for your text view and apply marque at the ending of the text i the xml file.

Comment: @CapDroid I want to use FirstName et al

Comment: @YasirAdnan you mean want to display only **A.Lambacher C.Leibig** instead of **A.Lambacher C.Leibig Gunther Zeck & T.Wachtler**?

Comment: Nope A.Lambacher et al

Comment: Check @Mocialov Boris 's answer. it will helpful..

Comment: @YasirAdnan:: you can marquee text for this situation

Answer (score 2):

```
//1) 
layout_width = yourLayout.getWidth(); //in order to measure the width of the ListView rows container
```

To find text size:

```
//2)
Paint paint = new Paint();
Rect bounds = new Rect();

int text_height = 0;
int text_width = 0;

paint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);// your preference here
paint.setTextSize(25);// have this the same as your text size

String text = "Some random text";

paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);

text_height =  bounds.height();
text_width =  bounds.width();

//3)

if(text_width < layout_width){
   //..do your magic
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794484/calculate-text-size-according-to-width-of-text-area)

Answer (score 2):

you can set your custom listview layout's `TextView` property as `android:ellipsize="end"` and also set the `android:singleLine="true"` in your `TextView`.

The TextView will use an ellipsize when it can not expand to show all of its text. The attribute ellipsized sets the position of the three dots if it is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this issue by checking how many lines does the **`TextView`** have after **`onSizeChanged`** finish, since only then you will have the real value of the number of lines.

First create an interface (you can define it on your desired `Fragment/Activity`)

```
public interface OnCustomTextViewSizeChangedListener {
    public void SizeChanged(int size);
}
```

Then create your custom `TextView`, `Override` onSizeChanged and create a function to define your listener.

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

    private OnCustomTextViewSizeChangedListener sizeChangeListener;
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        if(this.sizeChangeListener != null){
            this.sizeChangeListener.SizeChanged(getLineCount());
        }
    }

    public void setSizeChangeListener( OnCustomTextViewSizeChangedListener listener){
        this.sizeChangeListener = listener;
    }
}
```

Then just create your listener on your `Fragment/Activity`, define it for your desired `TextView` and your good to go!

```
OnCustomTextViewSizeChangedListener textViewSizeChanged = new  OnCustomTextViewSizeChangedListener() {

    @Override
    public void SizeChanged(int size) {
        if(size == 2){
           //Do your stuff here, like changing text size
        }
    }
}
```

PS: don't forget to change your layout to use your `CustomTextView`

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want your text view display in one line then do this-

```
textView.setMaxLines(1);
```

but Remember it cuts out the text which not fit in textview

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have a TextView displaying the text?

You can check if a textviews text is trimmed by calculating the width of TextView and also calculate the width of text which will be displayed in the textview:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    isMarqueed("I am fine here. How r u", textView.getWidth(), textView);
    isMarqueed("I am fine", textView.getWidth(), textView);
}


private boolean isMarqueed(String text, int textWidth, TextView tv) { 
    Paint testPaint = new Paint();
    testPaint.set(tv.getPaint());
    boolean isMarquee = true;

    if (textWidth > 0) {
        int availableWidth = (int) (textWidth - tv.getPaddingLeft() - tv.getPaddingRight()-testPaint.measureText(text));
        System.out.println("...available width..."+availableWidth);

        isMarquee = false;
    }
    return isMarquee;
}
```

Taken from here: [How to check if a TextView String has been trimmed (marquee)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187203/how-to-check-if-a-textview-string-has-been-trimmed-marquee)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a `TextView` you can use it's method `getLineCount()` to determine how many lines this `TextView` expands over. But be careful when using this method, you must be sure that the view has been drawn before invoking this method. See [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getLineCount%28%29) for more information.