# TextView ellipse disappears on setText()

Tags: java, android, textview

Good afternoon.

I have the following TextView:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/keypadwidget_number"
    android:tag="@string/phone_number_tag"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:ellipsize="start"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@color/widget_text"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/keypadwidget_btn_delete"/>
```

My expected result is to have the following:

```
...99862214
```

But instead, I'm getting:

[image]

*Sorry about the background/text colour. Not my choice!*

Each of those buttons call:

```
mPhoneNumberTextView.append(clickValue);
```

My question is; What am I doing wrong?

*EDIT:*
When I set the TextView's android:text property to something very long, the ellipse is set as expected. It's when `mPhoneNumberTextView.append(clickValue);` is run that it breaks.

Comment: I notice that this sometimes happens to me. The only workaround I've found is to use the maxLength attribute to specify the maximum number of characters that are allowed to fill the textView. Have you also tried setting the length of textView to match_parent?

Comment: Thank you for your response. The maxLength solution isn't helpful since I want to let the user enter text of any length. Also, I have tried to change the layout_width to match_parent but that's no help either.

Comment: Hmm. Looking at some code I have that works, I see that I also added the android:maxlines="1" attribute. Try adding that and removing the android:singleLine="true" and see if that works

Comment: android:singleLine is deprecated, use android:maxlines as suggested by Jade. Also use android:layout_width="fill_parent".

Comment: I'm not at work at the moment but the Docs don't mention anything about deprecation. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:singleLine
Could you please forward me to the resource that claims so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a fit of rage, I added a drawable to the left of the text view every time it was marqueed.

```
    private boolean isMarqueed(TextView tv){
        return isMarqueed(tv.getText().toString(), mPhoneNumberTextView.getWidth(), mPhoneNumberTextView);
    }

    private boolean isMarqueed(String text, int textWidth, TextView tv) {
        Paint testPaint = new Paint();
        testPaint.set(tv.getPaint());
        boolean isMarquee = true;
        if (textWidth > 0) {
            int availableWidth = (int) (textWidth - tv.getPaddingLeft() - tv.getPaddingRight()-testPaint.measureText(text));
            if(availableWidth > 0)
                isMarquee = false;
        }
        return isMarquee;
    }
```

Which is a slight variation of [How to check if a TextView String has been trimmed (marquee)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187203/how-to-check-if-a-textview-string-has-been-trimmed-marquee/6187781#6187781)

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` for your `TextView`